# Create symbolic links with cp preserving parent structure

Tags: shell, cp

I have the following folder structure:

```
.
`-- top_level/
    |-- sub-01_ses-01/
    |   `-- filtered_data.tar.gz*
    |-- sub-01_ses-02/
    |   `-- filtered_data.tar.gz*
    |-- sub-02_ses-01/
    |   `-- filtered_data.tar.gz*
    |-- sub-02_ses-02/
    |   `-- filtered_data.tar.gz*
```

**I wanted to create symbolic links to these files preserving the parent structure (since they all have the same filenames).**
Here's what I tried:

```
find -name "filtered_data.tar.gz" \
     -exec cp -s --parents --no-clobber -t /home/data/filtered {} \;
```

Now, I notice that cp does create the parent structure, but the symbolic links fail and I get the following notice:

> cp: `'/home/data/filtered/./sub-01_ses-01/filtered_data.tar.gz'`: can make relative symbolic links only in current directory

I'd like to understand why this is hapenning, and what the `cp` warning is trying to tell me. Also, any pointers on how to fix the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here: [symlink-copying a directory hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240636/symlink-copying-a-directory-hierarchy#comment8781244_1250782)

The path of the file to `cp` must be absolute, not `./something`. So, this should work for you:

```
find $(pwd) -name "filtered_data.tar.gz" \
     -exec cp -s --parents --no-clobber -t /home/data/filtered {} \;
```

Per your comment about what you're really trying to do, here's a Python script that does it. You should be able to tweak it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

target_filename = 'filtered_data.tar.gz'
top_src_dir = '.'
top_dest_dir = 'dest'

# Walk the source directory recursively looking for
# target_filename
for parent, dirs, files in os.walk(top_src_dir):
    # debugging
    # print(parent, dirs, files)

    # Skip this directory if target_filename not found
    if target_filename not in files:
        continue

    # Strip off all path parts except the immediate parent
    local_parent = os.path.split(parent)[-1]
    # Compute the full, relative path to the symlink
    dest_file = os.path.join(top_dest_dir, local_parent, target_filename)

    # debugging
    # print('{} {}'.format(dest_file, os.path.exists(dest_file)))

    # Nothing to do if it already exists
    if os.path.exists(dest_file):
        print('{} already exists'.format(dest_file))
        continue

    # Make sure the destination path exists
    dest_dir = os.path.dirname(dest_file)
    os.makedirs(dest_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Translate the relative path to target_filename
    # to be relative based on the new destination dir
    src_file = os.path.join(parent, target_filename)
    src_file = os.path.relpath(src_file, start=dest_dir)

    os.symlink(src_file, dest_file)
    print('{} --> {}'.format(dest_file, src_file))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed, but then I get **the whole parent structure**!. I only wanted the structure starting from `sub-XX_ses-XX`

Comment: It doesn't look like `cp` supports that. You'll probably have to write a script or a program (Python would be easy) to do this.